# Firestore where clause with security rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Suppose there are the following rules in place

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        function roomAccess() {
            return resource.data.allow_anonymous == true || (request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid);
        }
        function writeOnlyOwner() {
            return request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid;
        }
        match /rooms/{room_id} {
          allow read: if roomAccess();
          allow write: if writeOnlyOwner();
          allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
        }   
    }
}
```

Also, this is what an document in the collection `rooms` looks like
[image: Json format]

**Question** 
Is there any way to query the specific room where the `access_key` is set to some value?

```
 db.collection('rooms')
            .where('access_key', '==', access_key)
            .get()
```

It is important to note that i'm querying as the `creator` of the room (and the `room.uid` with match my `uid`

Nonetheless, it fails on access rights.
And the documentation doesn't seem to describe such behavior.

As far as I understood, the query fails because there might be `some` rooms, with this `access_key`, for which `roomAccess()` would fail. 
But I can't seem to find a way around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that I should have been checking for 
`resource.data.allow_anonymous == true || request.auth.uid != null` since I wanted to get the room either if the user is authenticated or it is public.

In this case, all the documents retrieved by `access_key` query match the security contraints